# Problema con el login php (no me redirecciona a mi pagina)

Tags: php, login

El problema es que cuando entro a la pagina hago el login y no puedo redireccionarme a mi pagina la cual esta en BASE_URL. En el usercontroller tengo que si esta logeado me mande a url home y todo okey (en url home tengo la pagina en blanco) pero si quiero redirigirme a la base url no hace nada y vuelve al login, la unica forma de entrar es sacando el checklogin y saltar la verificacion cambiando la url Cual seria el problema que no me deja redirigirme a mi pagina o sino como hago para trasladar la pagina a url_home. soy novato en php yy la verdad es que no la tengo muy clara y no se donde esta el problema

```
    <?php
    require_once "./models/usermodel.php";
    require_once "./Views/userview.php";

    class usercontroller {

        private $model;
        private $view;

        function __construct(){
            $this->model = new UserModel();
            $this->view = new UserView();
        }

        public function IniciarSesion(){
            $password = $_POST['pass'];
            $usuario = $this->model->GetPassword($_POST['user']);

            if (isset($usuario) && $usuario != null && password_verify($password, $usuario->password)){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user'] = $usuario->email;
                $_SESSION['userId'] = $usuario->id;
                header('Location:' . URL_HOME); // header("Location: " . BASE_URL); es donde tengo la pagina principal pero no me redirige 
            }else{
                header("Location: " . URL_LOGIN);
            }
        }

        public function Login(){
            $this->view->DisplayLogin();
        }


    }


        require_once "C:/xampp/htdocs/proyectos/mfindumentaria/controllers/indumentariacontroller.php";
        require_once "C:/xampp/htdocs/proyectos/mfindumentaria/controllers/usercontroller.php";

        $action = $_GET["action"];

        define("BASE_URL", 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].':'.$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'/');
        define("URL_LOGIN", 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].':'.$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'/login');
        define("URL_HOME", 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].':'.$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'/indumentaria');

        $controller = new mfindumentariacontroller();

        if($action == ''){
            $controller->getindumentaria();
        }
        else{
            if (isset($action)){
                $partesURL = explode("/", $action);

                if($partesURL[0] == "articulos"){
                    $controller->getindumentaria();

                }elseif($partesURL[0] == "insertar") {
                    $controller->insertararticulo();
                }
                if($partesURL[0] == "categorias"){
                    $controller->getindumentaria();
                }elseif($partesURL[0] == "insertar") {
                    $controller->insertarcategoria();
                }
                elseif($partesURL[0] == "mostrar"){
                    $controller->getcategoria($partesURL[1]);
                }
                }if($partesURL[0] == "borrararticulo") {
                $controller->borrararticulo($partesURL[1]);
                }
                if($partesURL[0] == "login") {
                    $controlleruser = new usercontroller();
                    $controlleruser->Login();
                }if($partesURL[0] == "iniciarSesion") {
                    $controlleruser = new usercontroller();
                    $controlleruser->IniciarSesion();
                }
            }

class UserModel {

    private $db;

    function __construct(){
        $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;'.'dbname=mfindumentaria;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
    }

    public function GetPassword($user){
        $sentencia = $this->db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = ?");
        $sentencia->execute(array($user));

        $password = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        return $password;
    }
}


class mfindumentariacontroller {

    private $modelindumentaria;
    private $modelcat;
    private $view;

    function __construct() {
        $this->modelindumentaria = new indumentariamodel();
        $this->modelcat = new categoriasmodel();
        $this->view = new indumentariaview();
    }

    private function checkLogIn() {
        session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
            header('Location: ' . URL_LOGIN);
            die();
        }

    }


    public function getindumentaria(){
        $this->checkLogIn();
        $mfindumentaria = $this->modelindumentaria->getarticulos();
        $cat = $this->modelcat->getcategorias();
        $this->view->displayindumentaria($mfindumentaria, $cat);

//y hago el checklogin en todas las funciones
    }


<?php
require_once "./models/usermodel.php";
require_once "./Views/userview.php";
```

Comment: ¿Y qué hay en el archivo al que apunta `BASE_URL`? ¿No habrá allí algún error o redirección de nuevo al login? ¿No hay redirecciones a nivel de `.htaccess`? Es lo primero que debes verificar, ¿ya lo hiciste?

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

    RewriteRule \.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ route.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>`
eso es mi .htacces y baseurl no apunta a ningun lado es la base url que yo tengo mi pagina ahi, localhost/proyectos/mfindumentaria seria donde tengo todo (BASE:URL)

Comment: ¿Si haces un `echo BASE_URL;` qué imprime? ¿Si copias  lo que imprime y lo pegas en la barra del navegador, entra en tu página BASE_URL?

Comment: Imprime http://localhost:80/proyectos/mfindumentaria, no no me deja me redirecciona al login

Comment: ¿Cuál debería ser la URL correcta para `BASE_URL`? Defínela primero a mano, tal cual. Me refiero a la URL válida que tú escribes desde la barra del navegador y te entra efectivamente en el contenido de tu página base. Me parece que lo que tienes aquí no es correcto: `define("BASE_URL", 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].':'.$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'/');` pues mira que produce una dirección no esperada.